# Disable follow on click in dnSpy decompilation view

Tags: dnspy

In the C# decompilation in dnSpy, single clicking on a class or method name takes you to the definition of it. This is handy, but I don't want it to happen every time I click almost anywhere. Sometimes I just want to highlight something to see where it's used. Is there some setting to change this behavior to require double click, or some keypress, as in most IDEs? I can't find it in Options, but maybe I missed it.

Comment: You can press `Alt`+`Click` (Don't follow the clicked reference so it's possible to start selecting text without being taken to the definition. References are only followed if none of `Ctrl`, `Alt` and `Shift` are pressed or if `Ctrl` is pressed.)

Comment: That works! I would prefer the opposite behavior but close enough. If you supply that as an answer I will accept it.